# When Angular DI removes its child injectors?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I want to use Angular DI as standalone module for Node's webserver.

I [have three levels DI](https://github.com/restify-ts/core/blob/3de4774bff4916bcaa3346926c35b84f414c3d56/src/server.ts#L274-L284):

- first level is root injector
- second level is child of root injector; its need per request for original Node's `http.IncomingMessage` and `http.ServerResponse`.
- third level is child of second injector; its need to create new instancies of my Request and Response classes, etc.

I worry about when DI removed child injectors. I need to removed them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I glanced the source code of injectors.
As a parent injector does not remember their children, it seems that they are removed together with the removal of a variable, where they were assigned.